# PHP session is either empty or doesn't work correctly

Tags: php, mysql, sql, session-variables

I am using the session variable `$_SESSION['staff_id']` to use as part of a condition in a query string. Just to see if the variable is working I set it to echo as the variable `$wombat` as seen in the code but instead it is empty. I don't know what I am doing incorrectly.

I have looked all over the place just to make sure my syntax is correct and to my knowledge it is.

```
<?php 
SESSION_START();
define('INCLUDE_CHECK',true);
if(isset($_SESSION['staff_id']))
$_SESSION['staff_id']=$wombat;
echo "'$wombat'";

// get the overall page header, including bootstrap and datatables libraries
// as well as the navbar menu for the top of the web page
require_once('task_assignment_header.php');

// load DB name and user credentials from single file for entire website
// this makes life easier later on
require_once('db_credentials.php');

?>
    <div class="container" style='margin-top:50px;'>

      <?php

        $StaffDBconnection = new mysqli($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_userpass, $db_dbname);

        // Check connection
        if (mysqli_connect_errno())
        {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        exit; // end program execution here
        }

        $resultset = mysqli_query($StaffDBconnection,"select t1.project_id, t1.project_name, t1.activeproject, t2.task_id, t2.taskname,
                                                      t2.taskstatus, t2.project_id, t3.staff_id, t3.fName, t3.lName, t4.staff_id, t4.task_id
                                                      from projects t1, tasks t2, employee t3, emp_tasks t4
                                                      where t1.activeproject = 'open'
                                                      and t2.taskstatus = 'in progress'
                                                      and t1.project_id = t2.project_id 
                                                      and t2.task_id = t4.task_id
                                                      and t3.staff_id = t4.staff_id
                                                      and t3.staff_id=" .$_SESSION['staff_id']);










        echo "<br><br>"; // put in a couple of blank lines at top below menu

        // This div tag makes the table "responsive" on smaller screens
        // and it also controls the overall width of the table.
        // Note that its width class of col-xs-5 is the sum of the width
        // classes used in the column heading (th) tags within the table, itself.
        echo "<div class='table-responsive col-xs-6'>";
                        // main table of data
            echo "<table id='assigntable' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' border='0' class='table table-striped table-bordered'>";
            echo "<thead><tr><th class='col-lg-4'>Project Name</th><th class='col-sm-4'>Task Name</th><th class='col-sm-4'>Employee Name</th></tr></thead><tbody>";

            while($AssignRow = mysqli_fetch_array($resultset))
              {
              $tmpID = $AssignRow['task_id'];
              $tmpprojid = $AssignRow['project_id'];


              echo "<tr><td>" . $AssignRow['project_name'] . "</td>" 
                     . "<td>" . $AssignRow['taskname'] . "</td>" . "<td>" . $AssignRow['fName']." ". $AssignRow['lName']. "</td>" . "</td>" ."</tr>";
               }

            echo "</tbody></table>";
            // end of main table of data

        echo "</div>"; // close out the responsive table div

        mysqli_close($StaffDBconnection);

      ?>



    </div><!-- /.container -->

<?php  
require_once('bootstrap_stafftable_footer.php');
?>
```

Comment: I think the condition in `if(isset($_SESSION['staff_id']))` should be flipped: `if(isset($_SESSION['staff_id']) === false)` else `staff_id` will never get a value.

Comment: Where is defined `$wombat`?Have you looked into your error log?

Comment: `SESSION_START()` should be lowercase `sesssion_start()`

Comment: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: You should really clarify exactly what it is you are trying to do and what you think should be happening. As it stands, there are a few possible answers.

Comment: As a general rule, please don't add "I need this by Friday", "urgent" or some other variation. Questions here are answered by volunteers very much at their own leisure. That said, there are plenty of people who can help here, so ask clear, well-researched questions and you'll not have a problem getting a quick answer.

Comment: I apologize i didnt mean to create a sense of urgency. I appreciate everyone's help and hope to one day to be intelligent enough to provide volunteer help for people that are currently in my situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assignment is invalid, also (I guess) you've forgotten to wrap your first `if` in braces.

```
session_start();
define('INCLUDE_CHECK',true);
if(isset($_SESSION['staff_id'])){
    $wombat = $_SESSION['staff_id'];
   echo "$wombat";
} else {
   echo "Undefined index 'staff_id'"; /*To check if $_SESSION['staff_id'] is not defined */
}
```